# Problems with itemize inside tabular and rotated text

Tags: tables, lists, vertical-alignment

I have some problems with a table in LaTeX. I want to have itemize inside cells and at the same time 90 degrees rotated text in the first column, vertically centered. I have a screenshot of the result I got so far, which does not look quite as I want - I think you know what I mean:

[image: Alignment problems]

Also, I would like to force the cells with itemize to use left alignment instead of full justification.

Thanks in advance :-)

The code to reproduce this table is listed here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
& Fuji X100s & Canon 6D & Nikon F100 & PHILM\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{Strengths} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Globally large
\item Many distribution centers
\item Well established
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Globally large
\item Many distribution centers
\item Well established
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Globally large
\item Many distribution centers
\item Well established
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Has a niche market
\item Easy distribution
\item Fits any ASLR
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{Weaknesses} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Big for a compact camera
\item Retro look only appeals to limited market
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Expensive
\item Big and bulky
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item No direct playback
\item Out dated
\item Expensive to develop film
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Market is limited
\item Battery life
\item No direct playback
\item Not ``established'' brand
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{Opportunities} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Retro look can be fashionable
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Utilization of Canon brand
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Photo enthusiast can revive 35mm photoshooting
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Photo enthusiast can revive 35mm photoshooting
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{Threats} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Competing brands can develop better cameras
\item Retro look no longer fashionable
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Competing brands can develop better cameras
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Digital cameras
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]%
\item Digital cameras
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Competitor SWOT analysis\label{tab:competitor-swot}}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the rotated labels, I used a combination of spaces and `\llap`.  For the justification, I invoked `\raggedright` for each itemize environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
& Fuji X100s & Canon 6D & Nikon F100 & PHILM\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Strengths~}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Globally large
\item Many distribution centers
\item Well established
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Globally large
\item Many distribution centers
\item Well established
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Globally large
\item Many distribution centers
\item Well established
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Has a niche market
\item Easy distribution
\item Fits any ASLR
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Weaknesses~}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Big for a compact camera
\item Retro look only appeals to limited market
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Expensive
\item Big and bulky
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item No direct playback
\item Out dated
\item Expensive to develop film
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Market is limited
\item Battery life
\item No direct playback
\item Not ``established'' brand
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{~~~~~~~\llap{Opportunities~}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Retro look can be fashionable
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Utilization of Canon brand
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Photo enthusiast can revive 35mm photoshooting
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Photo enthusiast can revive 35mm photoshooting
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Threats~~~~}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Competing brands can develop better cameras
\item Retro look no longer fashionable
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Competing brands can develop better cameras
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Digital cameras
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Digital cameras
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Competitor SWOT analysis\label{tab:competitor-swot}}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]