# itemize within a multirow

Tags: lists, itemize, multirow

I am a newbie. I wanted to use an itemize in a multirow. But latex shows an error. I found some similar questions but couldnt solve my problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
  \caption{Overview}
  \label{tab:data_overview}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{8.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ABC}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{XYZ}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{DEF}} \\
    \hline
    firstcol & secondcol & thirdcol\\
    \hline
        \multirow{7}{*}{firstcol} & secondcol & \multirow{7}{*}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item firstitem
            \begin{itemize}
            \item subitem1
            \end{itemize}
        \item seconditem
            \begin{itemize}
            \item subitem1
            \item subitem2
            \item subitem3
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
        }
    \\
    \hline

  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But it pops error as follows

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
```

Is there any options?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code as complete small document -- a Minimal Working Example (MWE) -- beginning with \documentclass{...}, follows with the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document} which demonstrate your problem. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them to help you.

Comment: Related?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148521/problems-with-itemize-inside-tabular-and-rotated-text

Answer (score 5):

First solution which employ `tabularx` environment has some malfunction: in column with itemize the width column is doesn't work as expected. So, meanwhile I found better solution with `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\tablistcommand}{% <-- for eliminating vertical space
                             %     before and after itemize
            \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                            }
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{p{#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\caption{Overview}
\label{tab:data_overview}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{P{0.2\textwidth}|}P{0.6\textwidth}|}
    \hline
\thead{ABC} &   \thead{XYZ} &   \thead{DEF}     \\
    \hline
first col   &   second col  &   third col third col third col third col third col third col third col third col third col   \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{7}{first\\ multirow}
           &   second col  & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0cm,noitemsep,topsep=0pt,                     
                    before = \tablistcommand,
                    after  = \tablistcommand]
    \item[] first item
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
        \item item 1
        \end{itemize}
    \item[] second item
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
        \item subitem 1
        \item subitem 2
        \item subitem 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}                               \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From your MWE is not evident, why for `itemize` you need `multirow` cell. As you can see, I use standard cell. In itemize I gave special care to vertical space before and after itemize.

For column heads I suggest to use macro `\thead` from package `makcell`. From it now I also use macros `\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells` which gives nice spacing of cell content. With their use increasing of `arraystretch` is surplus.

For vertical centering of text "first multirow" is used `\multirowcell` from `makecell`, which is slightly improved version of `multirow` macro.

**Addendum:**
If you for some reason persist to use `itemize` in `multirow` cell, than you need explicitly to define its with:

```
\multirow{<number of spanned lines>}{<width>}{<itemize>}
```

where `<number of spanned lines>` is number of lines in neighbor columns and `<width>` is width of column (it hadn't to be calculates in place, but determined in advance).

If number of spanned lines smaller than number of lines in `itemize`, you will be faced with remedy in table form. To resolve it will not be simple task.