# Longtable in Latex

Tags: tables, longtable

Could somebody give me a hint on this? I want to generate the table as shown in the photo.[image]

Since I was getting mistakes, I tried to create the table in excel and transfer it to Latex using a "ExceltoLatex"plugin which is shown in the code below. However, still it is not generating the table as I wanted it.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{clp{15.335em}l}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{RIBA Work Stage}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description of Key Tasks}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Core BIM Activities}} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Preparation}\end{sideways}} & \textbf{Appraisal} & Identification of client’s needs and objectives, business case, sustainability, life cycle and Facilities Management aspirations and possible constraints on development. Preparation of feasibility studies and assessment of options to enable the client to decide whether to proceed. & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{•Advise client on purpose of BIM including benefits and implications. Agree level and extent of BIM including 4D (time),  5D (cost) and 6D (FM) following software assessment. Advise client on Integrated Team scope of service in totality and for each designer including requirements for specialists and appointment of a BIM Model Manager.\newline{}•Define long-term responsibilities, including ownership of model.\newline{}• Define BIM Inputs and Outputs and scope of post-occupancy        evaluation (Soft Landings).\newline{}• Identify scope of and commission BIM surveys and investigation         reports.\newline{}• Data drop 1.}} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}          & \textbf{Design Brief} & Development of initial statement of requirements into the Design Brief by or on behalf of the client, confirming key requirements and constraints. Identification of procurement method, project sustainability and BIM procedures, building design lifetime and project organisational structure and range of consultants and others to be engaged for the project, including definition of responsibilities. &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass you use as well as the relevant packages? If you use the `geometry` package, please also add these settings to your question. (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: Since you mentioned `longtable` in your question: Will your table span multiple pages? Also, are you open to rotating your table to a landscape orientation to reduce the amount of white space? Are the bullet points in the last column somehow related to the two rows in the second/third column or do they just continue all teh way down without a correlation?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `tabularx` to make the table as wide as the textwidth, `enumitem` for the list in the last column, `makecell` for the column headers, and `multirow` for the contents in the first and last column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textbullet,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cl>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{RIBA Work Stage}} & \thead{Description of Key Tasks} & \thead{Core BIM Activities} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{24}[4]{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Preparation}}} 
        & \textbf{Appraisal} 
            & Identification of client’s needs and objectives, business case, sustainability, life cycle and Facilities Management aspirations and possible constraints on development. Preparation of feasibility studies and assessment of options to enable the client to decide whether to proceed. 
                & \multirow[t]{24}{=}{\begin{tabitem}
                                       \item advise client on purpose of BIM including benefits and implications. Agree level and extent of BIM including 4D (time),  5D (cost) and 6D (FM) following software assessment. Advise client on Integrated Team scope of service in totality and for each designer including requirements for specialists and appointment of a BIM Model Manager.
                                       \item Define long-term responsibilities, including ownership of model.
                                       \item Define BIM Inputs and Outputs and scope of post-occupancy evaluation (Soft Landings).
                                       \item Identify scope of and commission BIM surveys and investigation reports.
                                       \item Data drop 1.
                                   \end{tabitem}} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}          
    & \textbf{Design Brief} 
        & Development of initial statement of requirements into the Design Brief by or on behalf of the client, confirming key requirements and constraints. Identification of procurement method, project sustainability and BIM procedures, building design lifetime and project organisational structure and range of consultants and others to be engaged for the project, including definition of responsibilities. &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Probably you are also interested in a  entirely different presentation of the table contents. You could for example use nested description/itemize environments as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline]
    \item[Preparation]~
    \begin{description}
        \item[Appraisal] Identification of client’s needs and objectives, business case, sustainability, life cycle and Facilities Management aspirations and possible constraints on development. Preparation of feasibility studies and assessment of options to enable the client to decide whether to proceed. 
        \item[Design Brief] Development of initial statement of requirements into the Design Brief by or on behalf of the client, confirming key requirements and constraints. Identification of procurement method, project sustainability and BIM procedures, building design lifetime and project organisational structure and range of consultants and others to be engaged for the project, including definition of responsibilities.
    \end{description}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item advise client on purpose of BIM including benefits and implications. Agree level and extent of BIM including 4D (time),  5D (cost) and 6D (FM) following software assessment. Advise client on Integrated Team scope of service in totality and for each designer including requirements for specialists and appointment of a BIM Model Manager.
       \item Define long-term responsibilities, including ownership of model.
       \item Define BIM Inputs and Outputs and scope of post-occupancy evaluation (Soft Landings).
       \item Identify scope of and commission BIM surveys and investigation reports.
       \item Data drop 1.
    \end{itemize}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested tabulars are also a possibility, but the alignment is a challenge (*Example 1*). Your tabular can also quite easily be set as a `calstable`, using the [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) package. I also use [microtype](https://ctan.org/pkg/) for better line breaks and no warnings regarding overfull `hbox`es. (*Example 2*).

I have updated example 2 with a caption.  You add caption to at `calstable` in the same way as for other tabulars: Either you enclose the `calstable` in a `table-environment, or load the [capt-of][3] package and use the`\captionof{table}{command. I suggest that you load the complete [caption][3]-package so that you can format the caption. Unless you use [KOMA-script][3] of cause. Then you should use the internal command\captionofabove`:

**Example 1 – nested tabulars**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}p{0.3cm}p{3cm}m{4.75cm}m{5cm}@{}}
    \toprule
     &
     \small\bfseries RIBA Work Stage &
     \small\bfseries Description of Key Tasks &
     \small\bfseries Core BIM Activities\\ \midrule
     \begin{sideways}Preparation\end{sideways}  & 
     \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}>{\bfseries}m{3cm}m{4.755cm}@{}}
         Appraisal &
         Identification of client’s needs and objectives, business case, sustainability, life cycle and Facilities Management aspirations and possible constraints on development. Preparation of feasibility studies and assessment of options to enable the client to decide whether to proceed.\\ \midrule
         Design Brief &
         Development of initial statement of requirements into the Design Brief by or on behalf of the client, confirming key requirements and constraints. Identification of procurement method, project sustainability and BIM procedures, building design lifetime and project organisational structure and range of consultants and others to be engaged for the project, including definition of responsibilities.\\
\end{tabular}&
     &\begin{minipage}[b]{5cm}
     \begin{itemize}[labelsep=*, leftmargin=*, nosep]
\item Advise client on purpose of BIM including benefits and implications. Agree level and extent of BIM including 4D (time),  5D (cost) and 6D (FM) following software assessment. Advise client on Integrated Team scope of service in totality and for each designer including requirements for specialists and appointment of a BIM Model Manager.
\item Define long-term responsibilities, including ownership of model.
\item Define long-term responsibilities, including ownership of model.
\item Define BIM Inputs and Outputs and scope of post-occupancy        evaluation (Soft Landings)
\item Identify scope of and commission BIM surveys and investigation         reports.
\item Data drop 1
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabeladd}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – calstable**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating, caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{table}
\caption{You add caption to at calstable the usual way: Either enclose the calstable in a table-environment, or load the capt-of package and use the captionof command}

\begin{calstable}[c]

\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/20\relax}
            {\dimexpr((\columnwidth)/20)*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr((\columnwidth)/40)\relax}
            {\dimexpr((\columnwidth)/20)*7\relax}
            {\dimexpr((\columnwidth)/40)\relax}
            {\dimexpr((\columnwidth)/20)*7\relax}
            }

\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.8pt}   % Outside frame rules
\def\cals@framecs@width{0pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.6pt}  % Rule between header and tabular body
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}             % Inside vertical rules
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}              % Inside horizontal rules

\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else\let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

% H1
\thead{\bfseries\small
\brow
    \alignL\cell{}
    \alignL\cell{ RIBA Work Stage}
    \cell{}
    \alignL\cell{Description of Key Tasks }
    \cell{}
    \alignL\cell{Core BIM Activities}
\erow
\mdseries
}

%R1
\brow
    \nc{tlr}
    \alignL\cell{\vfil \textbf{Appraisal}}
    \cell{}
    \alignL\cell{Identification of client’s needs and objectives, business case, sustainability, life cycle and Facilities Management aspirations and possible constraints on development. Preparation of feasibility studies and assessment of options to enable the client to decide whether to proceed.}\bb
    \cell{}
    \nc{tlr}
\erow
%R2
\brow\bb
    \nc{blr}\alignL\sc{\vfil\begin{sideways}\textbf{Preparation}\end{sideways}}
    \alignL\cell{\vfil \textbf{Design Brief}}
    \cell{}
    \alignL\cell{Development of initial statement of requirements into the Design Brief by or on behalf of the client, confirming key requirements and constraints. Identification of procurement method, project sustainability and BIM procedures, building design lifetime and project organisational structure and range of consultants and others to be engaged for the project, including definition of responsibilities.}
    \cell{}
    \nc{blr}\alignL\sc{\begin{itemize}[labelsep=*, leftmargin=*, nosep]
\item Advise client on purpose of BIM including benefits and implications. Agree level and extent of BIM including 4D (time),  5D (cost) and 6D (FM) following software assessment. Advise client on Integrated Team scope of service in totality and for each designer including requirements for specialists and appointment of a BIM Model Manager.
\item Define long-term responsibilities, including ownership of model.
\item Define BIM Inputs and Outputs and scope of post-occupancy        evaluation (Soft Landings)
\item Identify scope of and commission BIM surveys and investigation         reports.
\item Data drop 1
\end{itemize}}
\erow

\makeatother
\end{calstable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help. In the second example, where can the code for table caption be inserted? when i tried to include caption i get an error "caption outside float".

Comment: @FaiselMoh'dMuktar See updated answer two: You add caption to at `calstable` as for other tabular: Either enclose the `calstable` in a `table`-environment, or load the capt-of package and use the [captionof](https://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) command. Unless you use [KOMA-script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) of cause. Then you use the internal command `\captionofabove`.

Comment: Thank you very much once again . For the question, I posted the code you provided me worked well. However, my table is about 3 pages long and the pattern changes at some rows, so I got stuck :'( ; plus I am not familiar with calstable. 

I thought that instead of including the actual long texts, I will use simple short texts but show the complete table style. 
If you see the question, please do reply; thanks.

Comment: @FaiselMoh'dMuktar calstable is multipage. For tabular, we need to change to longtable instead.

Comment: Ok thank you.
If you have time, please have a look at the question I posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/523202/revisions.

It is the same question, but I showed the complete table but with short sample texts.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

With use of the `makecell`, `multirow`, `tabularx` and `enumitem` package, redesigned column headers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\small\bfseries\hsize=0.24\hsize}R 
                                *{2}{>{\hsize=0.83\hsize}R} @{}}
    \toprule
\multirow{3}{=}{{RIBA Work Stage}}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Preparation}}    \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    &   \thead{Description of\\ Key Tasks} 
        &   \thead{Core BIM\\Activities}        \\
    \midrule
Appraisal
    &   Identification of client’s needs and objectives, business case, sustainability, life cycle and Facilities Management aspirations and possible constraints on development. Preparation of feasibility studies and assessment of options to enable the client to decide whether to proceed.
        &   \multirow{2}{=}{%
            \begin{itemize}[nosep, wide, before=\vspace{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
        \item   Advise client on purpose of BIM including benefits and implications. Agree level and extent of BIM including 4D (time),  5D (cost) and 6D (FM) following software assessment. Advise client on Integrated Team scope of service in totality and for each designer including requirements for specialists and appointment of a BIM Model Manager.
       \item    Define long-term responsibilities, including ownership of model.
       \item    Define BIM Inputs and Outputs and scope of post-occupancy evaluation (Soft Landings).\newline{}• Identify scope of and commission BIM surveys and investigation reports.
       \item    Data drop 1.
            \end{itemize}}              \\
    \addlinespace        
Design Brief
    &   Development of initial statement of requirements into the Design Brief by or on behalf of the client, confirming key requirements and constraints. Identification of procurement method, project sustainability and BIM procedures, building design lifetime and project organisational structure and range of consultants and others to be engaged for the project, including definition of responsibilities.
        &                                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Above solution consider showed table, for which is no need to use `longtable`. Instead of it is used `tabularx` (as in some other answer(s).

If your table really span multiple page, than you can easy adopt above code to such demand for example by use of the `xltabular`. If this is required, let me know, that I will provide code for it.

Comment: @Zako,

Thank you very much for the help. Yes, the table is about 3.5 pages; I have shown only the first part. 
Could you place the "Preparation" on the left side of the table? as there are also others I would like to include. The "Preparation" is the 1st work stage and the "Appraisal" and "Design Brief" are the sub-stages for the 1st stage. There are total 9 work stages.

Thanks

Comment: @FaiselMoh'dMuktar, `preparation` on the left side you have in other answers. I estimate, that this is not good solution. so I moved it on the top of table. That anyone will be able to help you, please, edit your question and extend your table fragment example to complete small document with table which has at least two pages with some dummy text.

Answer (score -1):

Courtesy @Steven B. Segletes --- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148524/197451

The below table format should suffice for your needs--do see if it meets your requirements

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
& RIBA Work Stage & Description of Key Task & Core BIM & PHILM\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Strengths~}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Globally large
\item Many distribution centers
\item Well established
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Globally large
\item Many distribution centers
\item Well established
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Globally large
\item Many distribution centers
\item Well established
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Has a niche market
\item Easy distribution
\item Fits any ASLR
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Weaknesses~}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Big for a compact camera
\item Retro look only appeals to limited market
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Expensive
\item Big and bulky
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item No direct playback
\item Out dated
\item Expensive to develop film
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Market is limited
\item Battery life
\item No direct playback
\item Not ``established'' brand
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{~~~~~~~\llap{Opportunities~}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Retro look can be fashionable
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Utilization of Canon brand
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Photo enthusiast can revive 35mm photoshooting
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Photo enthusiast can revive 35mm photoshooting
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Threats~~~~}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Competing brands can develop better cameras
\item Retro look no longer fashionable
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Competing brands can develop better cameras
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Digital cameras
\end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=1pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
\item Digital cameras
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Competitor SWOT analysis\label{tab:competitor-swot}}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where are the multirow commands that would be needed in the first and last column? Where is the bold text that the OP showed in the screenshot in their question and what about the vertical lines that are not present in the OP's code  nor in the screenshot?