# Table with rotated text (not centered) and itemize (begins far below)

Tags: tables, itemize, rotating

I'd like to make a classic SWOT table with rotated text and itemize which leads to some problems.

**Problem A:** The rotated text is not centered (see the coloured cells)

**Problem B:** The items from itemize start far below the right line.

I did find another similar example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148521/problems-with-itemize-inside-tabular-and-rotated-text). Unfortunately, I did not understand the solution very well I think.

**Attempt 1:** the centering and space above centering is wrong

[image]

**Attempt 2:** the centering is "fixed" (very ugly with protected spaces `~` and `\llp`). I really don't want to do this for ~30 tables manually. The spacing above itemize is still too long.

[image]

**Question:** How can I fix this? Is there a better way for the centering of the rotated text?
Please find code and picture of attempts attached.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}


% Colours from http://www.mostlycolor.ch/2013/10/colored-blocks-in-beamer.html
\colorlet{helpful}{lime!70}
\colorlet{harmful}{red!30}
\colorlet{internal}{yellow!20}
\colorlet{external}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{S}{helpful!50!internal}
\colorlet{W}{harmful!50!internal}
\colorlet{O}{helpful!50!external}
\colorlet{T}{harmful!50!external}
\colorlet{Tr}{red!50}

% Attempt 1 to make a good table Nr. 1
\newcommand{\swotTabOne}[4]{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{1em}X|m{1em}X|}\hline       
        \cellcolor{S}\rotatebox{90}{Stärken}   & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep] #1 \end{itemize} & 
        \cellcolor{W}\rotatebox{90}{Schwächen } &  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep] #2 \end{itemize}\\     \hline
        \cellcolor{O}\rotatebox{90}{Chancen }   & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep] #3 \end{itemize}& 
        \cellcolor{Tr}\rotatebox{90}{Risiken }   &  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep] #4 \end{itemize}\\     \hline
    \end{tabularx}
}

% Attempt 2
\newcommand{\swotTabTwo}[4]{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{1em}X|m{1em}X|}\hline       
        \cellcolor{S}\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Strengths~~~~~}}   & {\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]\raggedright #1 \end{itemize}} & 
        \cellcolor{W}\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Schwächen~~~~~}} &  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]\raggedright #2 \end{itemize}\\     \hline
        \cellcolor{O}\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Chancen }}   & \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]\raggedright #3 \end{itemize}& 
        \cellcolor{Tr}\rotatebox{90}{\llap{Risiken~ }}   &  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]\raggedright #4 \end{itemize}\\     \hline
    \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{SWOT analysis for Idea 2}\label{tab:swot_1}
    \swotTabOne{\item strength 1 \item this is a very long strength, so much length wow \item another very long strength, absoluteley amzing such wow}
        {\item weakness 1 \item weakness 2 \item weakness 3}
        {\item amazing opportunity \item oh wow so much opportunity}
        {\item risk \item oh this damn risk}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{SWOT analysis for Idea 2}\label{tab:swot_2}
    \swotTabTwo{\item strength 1 \item this is a very long strength, so much length wow \item another very long strength, absoluteley amzing such wow}
        {\item weakness 1 \item weakness 2 \item weakness 3}
        {\item amazing opportunity \item oh wow so much opportunity}
        {\item risk \item oh this damn risk}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: For top alignment instead of vertical centering, replace all `m` column types with `p`.

Comment: Thank you, @Mico. Unfortunately, this did not solve the vertical centering problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical centering in the following answer isn't perfect, but I daresay that it's better than in the OP's example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % <-- new
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % <-- new
\usepackage{enumitem,ragged2e}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1} % <-- new
\setlist[myitemize]{label=\textbullet,left=0pt,noitemsep,
                    before={\RaggedRight\begin{minipage}{\hsize}},
                    after={\end{minipage}}}
%\usepackage{makecell}


% Colours from http://www.mostlycolor.ch/2013/10/colored-blocks-in-beamer.html
\colorlet{helpful}{lime!70}
\colorlet{harmful}{red!30}
\colorlet{internal}{yellow!20}
\colorlet{external}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{S}{helpful!50!internal}
\colorlet{W}{harmful!50!internal}
\colorlet{O}{helpful!50!external}
\colorlet{T}{harmful!50!external}
\colorlet{Tr}{red!50}

% Attempt 1 to make a good table Nr. 1
\newcommand{\swotTabOne}[4]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| m{1em} X  m{1em} X |}
    \hline       
      \cellcolor{S}\rotatebox{90}{Stärken}   
    & \begin{myitemize} #1 \end{myitemize} 
    & \cellcolor{W}\rotatebox{90}{Schwächen } 
    & \begin{myitemize} #2 \end{myitemize}\\    
    \hline
      \cellcolor{O}\rotatebox{90}{Chancen }   
    & \begin{myitemize} #3 \end{myitemize}
    & \cellcolor{Tr}\rotatebox{90}{Risiken }   
    & \begin{myitemize} #4 \end{myitemize}\\    
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example

\begin{table}[htb]
   \caption{SWOT analysis for Idea 2}
   \label{tab:swot_1}
   \swotTabOne%
   {\item strength 1\strut \item this is a very long string, so 
          much length wow \item another very long string, absoluteley 
          amazing such wow}
   {\item weakness 1 \item weakness 2 \item weakness 3}
   {\item amazing opportunity \item oh wow so much opportunity}
   {\item risk \item oh this damn risk}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mico. :)

Answer (score 3):

With use of `tabularray` package the vertical centering is not perfect, but it’s a pretty good approximation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating, makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                     leftmargin = *         ,
                     label      = $\bullet$ ,
                     before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                     after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{SWOT analysis for Idea 2}\label{tab:swot_2}
\label{tab:table-tblr}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Schwächen}        % from makecell
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[m] X[1.2,l,m] Q[c,m] X[0.8,l,m]},
             measure = vbox,            % <----
         column{1,3} = {cmd=\rotcell},  % <----
            }
\SetCell[c=1]{bg=yellow!30}   \hfil Stärken  
    &   \begin{tabitemize}
    \item strength 1
    \item this is a very long strength, so much length wow
    \item another very long strength, absolutely amazing such wow
        \end{tabitemize}
        &   \SetCell[c=1]{bg=red!30} Schwächen 
            &   \begin{tabitemize}
            \item weakness 1 
            \item weakness 2 
            \item weakness 3
                \end{tabitemize}        \\    
\SetCell[c=1]{bg=olive!30}  \hfil   Chancen
    &   \begin{tabitemize}
    \item amazing opportunity 
    \item oh wow so much opportunity
        \end{tabitemize}
        &   \SetCell[c=1]{bg=purple!30} \hfil Risiken
            &   \begin{tabitemize}         
            \item risk 
            \item oh this damn risk
                \end{tabitemize}       \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Zarko. :)